# Puppet firewall module does not recognise the 'security' table

Tags: puppet, firewall

Trying to add a firewall rule to the security ip table. Support for the security table was added in version 1.8.0 and I'm running 1.9.0 so everything should be okay. However, the following error is spat out

Invalid value "security". Valid values are nat, mangle, filter, raw, rawpost

Comment: A [mre] would make this much easier to answer.  Among the things it should make clear is whether that message coming from Puppet or from the target node firewall-management tool that Puppet is using.  (If the latter, then the basic answer is "don't do that".)

Comment: Add your discovery as an issue on github for `https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-firewall` and somebody should be able to take a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that even the development branch of the `firewall` module doesn't accept `security` as a value for the `table` parameter of the `firewall` resource.

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-firewall/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/firewall.rb#L579

That said, the `firewallchain` resource does accept `security` as a table name, so the module is aware of it, but there doesn't appear to be a way of adding firewall rules.